# Batch String +=?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, variables, cmd

I want to add x times "# " to a string.

This is my attempt:

```
set line=

for /L %%a in (1,1,%amount%) do (
    set "line=%line%# "
)
```

In other programming languages, for example python, it'd look like this:

```py
line = ""

for i in range(amount):
    line += "# "
```

But, I have no clue how this would work in batch...
I'd be very happy if somebody could help me, thanks :)

Comment: In a for-loop, you can't access the current value with `%line%`, but with `!line!`

Comment: …which only works when [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled…